# CSS Image and text on the right

Tags: html, css, image, text

I need to put a text near the images..
This is the **CSS** code generated to show the images:

**CSS:**

```
#showbox {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
width: 973;
height: 46px;
background: white repeat;
z-index: 12;
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
    }
#showbox span {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
#showbox a {
width: 100%;
display: inline;
text-indent: -900%;
position: absolute;
outline: none;
  }
  #showbox a:hover {
background-position: left bottom;
  }
   #showbox a:hover span{
display: inline;
  }
  #showbox .one {
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: url(images/cerchio1.png) no-repeat;
   }
   #showbox .two {
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
top: 0;
left: 240px;
background: url(images/cerchio2.png) no-repeat;
  }
    #showbox .three {
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
top: 0px;
left: 480px;
margin-right: 12px;
background: url(images/cerchio3.png) no-repeat;
    }
    #showbox .four {
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
top: 0px;
left: 720px;
margin-right: 12px;
background: url(images/cerchio4.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="showbox">
<a class="one"></a>
<a class="two"></a>
<a class="three"></a>
<a class="four"></a>
</div>
```

---

What I have to do if i want the text on the right of the images?
I have to create another box for the text ?
This code for the images is ok or is possible to remove some parts of code? thanks

Comment: Why are you putting your images in the background instead of using `img` tags?

Comment: Do you need a text in each link, after every image (in the right) or in the right side of the images group/zone?

Comment: Yes I need [IMAGE]    Text...    [IMAGE]    Text...  with a little bit of margin on the right from the image and on top to align in the middle of the image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks pretty strange to me. I assume that you want to use the images for links, yes? In that case, I'd suggest changing your HTML to this:

```
<div id="showbox">
    <div class="one"><a><img src="images/img1.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="two"><a><img src="images/img2.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="three"><a><img src="images/img3.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="four"><a><img src="images/img4.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

To add text to the immediate left of the images, we simply write it out:

```
<div id="showbox">
    <div class="one"><a><img src="images/img1.jpg"></a>Text</div>
    <div class="two"><a><img src="images/img2.jpg"></a>Text</div>
    <div class="three"><a><img src="images/img3.jpg"></a>Text</div>
    <div class="four"><a><img src="images/img4.jpg"></a>Text</div>
</div>
```

Doing this, you should be able to get the desired result with this CSS:

```
#showbox {
    padding: 0;
    width: 973;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 12;
    position: relative;
}
#showbox .one {
    position:absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 46px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#showbox .two {
    position:absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 46px;
    top: 0;
    left: 240px;
}
#showbox a, img {
    float:left;
}
```

I to demonstrate, I created [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VWEX/2/). I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

To position the text in the middle of the image vertically, we need to tinker a bit; vertical aligning isn't HTML's strongest side. But it is possible.

Fistly, you need to edit the CSS a bit. For each class `.one`, `.two`, `.three`, `.four` you need to add

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

The `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` makes sure to position elements within the box in the vertical middle, so to speak. Unfortunately, this isn't enough (did I mention that vertical aligning isn't HTML's strongest side?). We also need to add

```
#showbox p{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
```

to the CSS. We also add `margin-right:5px;` to the `#showbox img,a` clause in the CSS:

```
#showbox a, img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

This is to make sure that all HTML and text to the right of the image or link is moved 5px away from the image or link.

And, finally, in the HTML we simply put the text within `<p>` tags, like so:

```
<div id="showbox">
    <div class="one">
        <a><img src="images/img1.jpg"></a>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <a><img src="images/img2.jpg"></a>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <a><img src="images/img3.jpg"></a>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="four">
        <a><img src="images/img4.jpg"></a>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To demonstrate, I've [updated the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VWEX/5/).

Comment: Yes that's good but i need some space from the images for the text.. top  and right.. how i can do this ?

Comment: @user3047517 I've edited my post, please take a look.